# How Do I Stop FileVault from Decrypting my MacBook Pro?

Tags: filevault

Somehow I stupidly started to turn off my FileVault on my MacBook Pro.  Not exactly sure how I did this, brain fart.  Now my machine is trying to decrypt what I assume are all my files.  Right now I have the decryption paused, but it is waiting for me to hook up my power cable to complete the decryption.  I'm afraid when I run out of power and hook up my power cable to recharge my machine, the decryption will restart.  I want to stop this process and go back to the way my machine was before.  Is there some way for me to stop the decryption and restart the FileVault?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your FireVault settings. I have a feeling that I know whats wrong...

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to have taken care of itself.  I am now in the process of encrypting my hard drive.  I appreciate your help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, let it complete and then turn FileVault back on once it's done. Not elegant but should work.

Comment: Yeah, honestly I can't see anything good coming out of interrupting a full-disk encryption/decryption process.

Comment: As I told YusaMac205, the problem seems to have fixed itself.  Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @DanfromVA Could you elaborate on what you mean by "fixed itself"?